# return redirect with json response in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to redirect to an url with json response, how can I do that ? for example :

I was trying by the following code so far :

```
  return redirect("C:\laravel\cyberSeuritySummit2021\cyberSecuritySummit")->response()- 
  >json(['success'=>'Payment Successful !']);
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#redirects refer this

Comment: "_I want to redirect to an url with json response_" What does that mean? Redirect to the url, which in turn should return a json response. Not sure if you can redirect to a local file `C:\laravel`

Comment: Or you redirect, Or you return a response. You can't do both. And as brombeer commented, don't redirect to a local file.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do both at the same time return the URL and your message.

```
 return response()->json([
'success'=>'Payment Successful !',
'URL' => "C:\laravel\cyberSeuritySummit2021\cyberSecuritySummit"
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need get back message try use

```
redirect()->route('route')->with('message', $message);
```

what use session.

or `redirect()->away()` if not on your site..

Comment: He wanted to redirect back with a url.

Comment: "I want to redirect to an url with json response" he say.. JSON response to sand 'success' message..

Comment: Ok, i see.. not route()

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can redirect to a directory in your computer.On the other hand as an option, İf you need json, you can parse it in the redirected url;

```
    return redirect('cyberSecuritySummit')->with('message', json_encode(['success'=>'Payment sucessfull!']));
```